# capistrano deploy without destination production box access to the git box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

So I have a situation where we migrated our stash(git repo) environment to a different box.Let's call this stash_box.

Now, previously this was my process to deploy to prod.

I have a secure linux box, which is used for deployment. Lets call this deploy_box.

Let's call the destination prod server prod_box.

Now previously the procuction boxes had ssh access to the stash box(prod_box -> stash_box)

So when I pull the code from the deploy_box & run

```
cap prod_box deploy
```

It used to deploy successfully.

Now, there is a firewall rule that **does no**t allow the prod_box to talk to the stash_box which has the git repo.

As far I understand capistrano needs a connection between the destination server & the stash server.

Now, The deploy_box can reach the stash_box as well as the prod_box both ways.

Is there a way to achieve the production deployment by modifying existing capistrano script?

This is my existing deploy.rb file:

```
require "capistrano/ext/multistage"
require "bundler/capistrano"


SECURE_FILES = ['database.yml', 'initializers/secret_token.rb']

set :application,   "myapp"
set :use_sudo,      false

set :scm,           :git
set :repository, "ssh://git@stash_box:7999/web/myapp.git"
set :user, "webuser"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

after "deploy:update_code", "custom:create_symlinks", "custom:assets_precompile", "custom:miscellaneous"
after "deploy", "deploy:migrate"
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Restarting mod_rails with restart.txt"
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  [:start, :stop].each do |t|
    desc "#{t} task is a no-op with mod_rails"
    task t, :roles => :app do ; end
  end

end

namespace :custom do

  desc "Assets Pre-Compilation"
  task :assets_precompile, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_release} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
  end
end
```

This is my prod_box.rb file:

```
server "prod_box", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true

set :deploy_to, "/opt/web/var/my_app"
set :rails_env, "customertest"
set :branch, "staging"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a different deployment strategy:

```
set :deploy_via, :copy
```

Now the source code will be checked out locally and uploaded to remote. You can read more about that [here](http://bu.chsta.be/blog/2013-02-24/capistrano-deployment-strategies-deploy-via-a-copy/)

**Edit**

For capistrano v3 you'll have to use this [gem](https://github.com/xuwupeng2000/capsitrano-scm-gitcopy), and specify:

```
set :scm, :gitcopy
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Is there a reason why the capistrano 3 removed the deploy_via copy method? Are there some flaws associated with the above approach

Comment: You can read the discussion [here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/695). TL; DR; Authors didn't want to maintain this feature, due to differences across platforms.

Comment: Thanks. but seems like it is an important feature that should come with capistrano, as many production systems don't have direct access to the source code.